# A Status code indicating if the top-level call succeeded or failed (applicable for Post BYZANTIUM blocks only)

Tags: ether, etherscan, python

When i try to swap from bnb to busd its working fine but when i try to swap between other coins is giving me error , also i try to swap from busd to other coins same error

A Status code indicating if the top-level call succeeded or failed (applicable for Post BYZANTIUM blocks only

what i am doing wrong?

````
pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
  1074184953676691292, # here setup the minimum destination token you want to have, you can do some math, or you can put a 0 if you don't want to care
  [spend,contract_id],
  sender_address,
  (int(time.time()) + 1000000)
).buildTransaction({
  'from': sender_address,
  'value': web3.toWei(0.01,'ether'),#This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
  'gas': 250000,
  'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
  'nonce': nonce,
})
 
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)```
````

Comment: Do you have a failed transaction hash?